# Selecting from DATETIME field?

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I am doing mySQL queries as such selecting a unix time stamp from a database, like so:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time)) AS theday, COUNT(id) AS thecount FROM `table`
WHERE `time`>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - > INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
GROUP BY theday 
ORDER by theday DESC
```

How would I go about doing a similar query but selecting a DATETIME format? Instead of a unix time stamp?

For example,

> 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: what is the datatype of time field ?

Comment: Did you ever try to read a mysql documentation? Just to understand what are all these functions you are using do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think MySql DATE_FORMAT will work for you.

```
mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS theday, COUNT(id) AS thecount FROM table WHERE time>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 14 DAY) GROUP BY theday ORDER by theday DESC");
```

Comment: Hi there, I have tried this but I think "WHERE `when`>=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 14 DAY)" is causing errors?

Comment: Try this WHERE date_format(`time`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)

Comment: I seemed to get this to work:

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( `when` ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS theday, COUNT( id ) AS thecount
FROM  `table` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( `when` ,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 14 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY theday
ORDER BY theday DESC 


Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

## Update:

---

Based on your comment, you can use [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to select date portion from your datetime field:

```
SELECT DATE(time)
```

---

> How would I go about doing a similar
>   query but selecting a DATETIME format?
>   Instead of a unix time stamp?

Instead of:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(time))
```

You can select your datetime field directly:

```
SELECT time
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but when doing so, it selects theday as 2011-01-03 20:29:06 for example - and it is not grouped by individual days then, as it has the time on the end of it too. How do we work around this to just get 2011-01-03? Happy new year!